# Attempted import error: 'Component' is not exported from './UserOutput/UserOutput'

Tags: reactjs

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import UserInput from './USerInput/UserInput';
import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';
```

**userinput succesfully imported but userOutput in not exporting and showing an error**

UserOutput.js

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
```

Comment: Please update question a bit with error , and usually the log. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 4):

I think this is an issue with the React app.

Make sure this is the current structure of your App.js file.

```
 import React, { Component } from "react";
 import "./App.css";

 import UserInput from './USerInput/UserInput';
 import UserOutput from './UserOutput/UserOutput';

    class App extends Component {

    render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">

           <UserInput  />
           <UserOutput /> 

      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Your imports will work then.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot to export from component.

UserOutput.js

```
   export default UserOutput;
    or
   export default class UserOutput extends React.Component{}
```

import anywhere

```
   import UserOutput from './...'
```

And import your `Component` like this or use direct `React.Component`

Ways

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
```

and use like this

```
   class UserOutput extends Component{}
    or
   class UserOutput extends React.Component{}  // if you don't import Component
```

Comment: i export from both component just like ^^^  export default UserInput;^^^  and ^^^  export default UserOutput;^^^

Comment: @FaisalNadeem what's the error that you are getting?

Comment: ./src/App.js
Attempted import error: 'Component' is not exported from './UserOutput/UserOutput'.

Comment: have you done this ? import React,{Component} from 'react';?